# NEON: How to I get my SoA 4x quaternion-to-matrix out to array of non-interleaved 4x4 matrices?

Tags: optimization, arm, simd, neon

I am still learning all the best ways to work with NEON, and here is my problem. I have a quaternion-to-matrix operation that needs to operate on an array of quaternions and then add translation in to make a 4x4 matrix. I have the data arranged in an SOA and have written the following using intrinsics that operates on 4 quaternions at a time

```
// two constants
float32x4_t one = { 1.f, 1.f, 1.f, 1.f };
float32x4_t two = { 2.f, 2.f, 2.f, 2.f };

// load the data 4 quaternions wide
float32x4_t rot_x = vld1q_f32(data->rotation_x); // load 4 quatenion's worth of x's
float32x4_t rot_y = vld1q_f32(data->rotation_y); // load 4 quatenion's worth of y's
float32x4_t rot_z = vld1q_f32(data->rotation_z); // load 4 quatenion's worth of z's
float32x4_t rot_w = vld1q_f32(data->rotation_w); // load 4 quatenion's worth of w's


float32x4_t qxx2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_x, rot_x ), two );
float32x4_t qyy2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_y, rot_y ), two );
float32x4_t qzz2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_z, rot_z ), two );
float32x4_t qxy2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_x, rot_y ), two );
float32x4_t qxz2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_x, rot_z ), two );
float32x4_t qyz2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_y, rot_z ), two );
float32x4_t qxw2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_x, rot_w ), two );
float32x4_t qyw2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_y, rot_w ), two );
float32x4_t qzw2 = vmulq_f32( vmulq_f32( rot_z, rot_w ), two );


float32x4_t m11 = vsubq_f32( one, vsubq_f32( qyy2, qzz2 ) );
float32x4_t m21 = vsubq_f32( qxy2, qzw2 );
float32x4_t m31 = vaddq_f32(qxz2, qyw2);

float32x4_t m12 = vaddq_f32(qxy2, qzw2);
float32x4_t m22 = vsubq_f32( one, vsubq_f32( qxx2, qzz2 ) );
float32x4_t m32 = vsubq_f32(qyz2, qxw2);

float32x4_t m13 = vsubq_f32( qxz2, qyw2 );
float32x4_t m23 = vaddq_f32( qyz2, qxw2);
float32x4_t m33 = vsubq_f32( one, vsubq_f32( qxx2, qyy2 ) );
```

This gives me 4 3x3 matrices with the rotation.

In the end, I need to create four 4x4 matrices with translation where M14, M24, M34 are 0, and the translation is stored in M41, M42, M43, and M44 is 1.f.

```
struct Matrix
{
  float m11, m12, m13, m14;
  float m21, m22, m23, m24;
  float m31, m32, m33, m34;
  float m41, m42, m43, m44;
};
```

But I don't know how to efficiently extract the data from the NEON registers. I have tried simply storing the data from the NEON Registers and then manipulating it, but obviously the performance is bad. I would like to include the translation in the most efficient way possible, but I don't think loading a vector just to store it really helps?

Any insight would be helpful. What am I looking for here?

Comment: Do you want to convert four quaternions stored in SoA format to four individual matrices (if so, why not keep them in SoA as well)? If that is really what you want, you need to look how to interleave multiple registers (I'm no NEON expert, but `vtrn` or `vzip` look promising).

Comment: I wish I could leave the matrices in SoA but there is client code that wants them not interleaved. I will look at vtrn and zip.

Comment: Maybe change "create a 4x4 matrix" to "create four 4x4 matrices". And btw, you can save quite a lot `vmulq_f32(..., two)` by only multiplying `rot_x`,...,`rot_z` by two (or add them to themselves): `rot_2x = rot_x+rot_x; qxx2 = rot_2x*rot_x;', etc.

Comment: @chtz You are right - the reference code I was using does not do that and I was simply translating it to NEON. I made the changes in the reference code and surprisingly my compiler's assembly had already made those optimizations in the scalar assembly. Not in the NEON, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure NEON has enough vector registers, but you can try something like this, untested:

```
inline float32x4_t unpackLow( float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b )
{
    float32x2_t x = vget_low_f32( a );
    float32x2_t y = vget_low_f32( b );
    return vcombine_f32( x, y );
}

inline float32x4_t unpackHigh( float32x4_t a, float32x4_t b )
{
    float32x2_t x = vget_high_f32( a );
    float32x2_t y = vget_high_f32( b );
    return vcombine_f32( x, y );
}

const float32x4_t zero = vdupq_n_f32( 0 );
const float32x4_t lastRow = vsetq_lane_f32( 1, zero, 3 );

// Zip them pairwise
const float32x4x2_t r11 = vzipq_f32( m11, m12 );
const float32x4x2_t r12 = vzipq_f32( m13, zero );
const float32x4x2_t r21 = vzipq_f32( m21, m22 );
const float32x4x2_t r22 = vzipq_f32( m23, zero );
const float32x4x2_t r31 = vzipq_f32( m31, m32 );
const float32x4x2_t r32 = vzipq_f32( m33, zero );

// Produce the matrices
vst1q_f32( pointer, unpackLow( r11.val[ 0 ], r12.val[ 0 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 4, unpackLow( r21.val[ 0 ], r22.val[ 0 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 8, unpackLow( r31.val[ 0 ], r32.val[ 0 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 12, lastRow );

vst1q_f32( pointer + 16, unpackHigh( r11.val[ 0 ], r12.val[ 0 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 20, unpackHigh( r21.val[ 0 ], r22.val[ 0 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 24, unpackHigh( r31.val[ 0 ], r32.val[ 0 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 28, lastRow );

vst1q_f32( pointer + 32, unpackLow( r11.val[ 1 ], r12.val[ 1 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 36, unpackLow( r21.val[ 1 ], r22.val[ 1 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 40, unpackLow( r31.val[ 1 ], r32.val[ 1 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 44, lastRow );

vst1q_f32( pointer + 48, unpackHigh( r11.val[ 1 ], r12.val[ 1 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 52, unpackHigh( r21.val[ 1 ], r22.val[ 1 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 56, unpackHigh( r31.val[ 1 ], r32.val[ 1 ] ) );
vst1q_f32( pointer + 60, lastRow );
```

These vget_low / vget_high / vcombine are relatively cheap, the assembly has names to address the 64-bit pieces of these registers.

If that won’t work well due to registers shortage, second option is ZIP just the central elements, `vzipq_f32( m11, m12 )`, `vzipq_f32( m21, m22 )`, `vzipq_f32( m31, m32 )`, then use vget_low / vget_high for them, 64-bit vector stores i.e. `vst1_f32` to write the corresponding matrix elements in pairs, and `vst1q_lane_f32` to store individual scalars extracted from your m13, m23, m33 vectors.

Comment: This seems to yield the right results. I'll have to check again tomorrow how the performance works. Like most SO questions there is more to this puzzle and I need to put the other pieces in there (scale and translation), but the shifting works great, thank you.